# How to compare 2 formatted fields and using them for where clause condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have been trying to compare 1 field to itself by converting it to 'ddMMyyyy' and trying to execute it

Data example:

```
User    | DateTime
AU      | 01-04-2022 11:11:11
AU      | 01-04-2022 12:09:30
SG      | 04-08-2023 03:23:01
NA      | 21-11-2022 15:10:40
```

I've tried doing this, DateTime consist of a few data of date and time where the original format is "01-01-2022 11:12:09"

```
select *
    format(DateTime, 'ddMMyyyy') AS DT
where DT != DT FROM TblUser
```

are there any way to do this?

My expectation on this would be that it will show the fields where DT does not have the same value of itself.

Expected result would be:

```
User    | DateTime
SG      | 04082023
NA      | 21112022
```

Comment: DT != DT will always return no rows (becuase it is always false). Describing why you want to do this can get you more answers; is it because the DateTime column is of type datetime and it has non-zero time components and you want to see those cases? or is it that the DateTime column is varchar/nvarchar and you want to see if it can be converted to date successfully? or is there a column called DT in your table and you want to compare that?

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results, because as it stands it doesn't make sense.

Comment: Just an aside.  Try to avoid reserved words like USER and DATETIME.  Take a peek at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/reserved-keywords-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: "My expectation on this would be that it will show the fields where DT does not have the same value of itself." this doesn't make sense - what "itself"? I think you must want to compare values across different rows? Which isn't the normal way a query works... so are you saying all rows which don't match the first row? Or something? Or do you mean rows that only occur once? (Thats seems to be what the answer below provides).

Comment: @DaleK yes I would want to compare different rows of the same column, if the column's row has the same value it will not be shown.

Comment: Same value as what? Just already exists in the table? So actually you are asking for all rows, there that row is the only row to occur on that date?

Answer (score 0):

One option is using WITH TIES.

I don't like using `format()`, especially with large tables.   Personally, I would just `convert(date,[datetime])`

**Example**

```
Select top 1 with ties 
       [User]
      ,[DateTime] = format([Datetime],'ddMMyyyy')
 From TblUser
 Order By sum(1) over (partition by [User],convert(date,[DateTime]))
```

**Results**

```
User    DateTime
NA      21112022
SG      04082023
```

**EDIT: If by chance your `[DateTime]` column is a string**

```
Select top 1 with ties 
       [User]
      ,[DateTime] = replace(left([DateTime],10),'-','')
 From TblUser
 Order By sum(1) over (partition by [User],left([DateTime],10))
```

Answer (score 0):

For the comparison I am assuming that you want rows where the "date" is without the time of day. (In reality, if the data type is `datetime` then any "just date" will also have the time of 00:00:00.000.) So, to ignore the time of day (except those with time NOT at 00:00:00.000) then convert the date type from `datetime` to `date`.

nb: The clauses must be in order `SELECT` then `FROM` then `WHERE`

```
SELECT
      TblUser.*
    , format([DateTime], 'ddMMyyyy') AS DT
FROM TblUser
WHERE [DateTime] != convert(date,[DateTime])
```

If you really needed to use the `column alias` "DT" then you need a `derived table` like this:

```
SELECT
    format(DT, 'ddMMyyyy') AS DTfinal
FROM (
    SELECT
          TblUser.*
        , convert(date,[DateTime]) AS DT -- the "column alias" is created here
    FROM TblUser
     ) AS derived
WHERE DT != [DateTime] -- now you can use the "column alias" DT
```

**BUT** do not use `format()` when forming the column "DT" because you cannot reliably compare the string (in ddMMyyyy format) to a `date` or a `datetime` value.

nb: the `format()` function returns a string even if you comprehend ddMMyyyy to represent a date.

Answer (score 0):

A simple aggregation will do the job:

```
select [User], format([DateTime], 'ddMMyyyy') AS DT 
from  table_name
group by [User], format([DateTime], 'ddMMyyyy')
having count(*) = 1
```